# Using Visual Studio Designer to handle multiple possible form layouts

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Is there a good way to use VS's designer to help in the case where you've got multiple possible layouts for a form?

i.e., say condition1 you put these controls up at the top and those controls in the middle, or condition2 you put those controls up at the top and these controls toward the left in a larger font.  And various things like that.

It seems like this should be common enough that VS designer should be able to handle this sort of thing cleanly, but everything I've tried is either clunky or requires hand-coding the dimensions without designer support.  Is there a best-practice for handling these sorts of things?  I'm open to either WPF or WinForms solutions.

Also, creating two different forms isn't really my preference, since most of the controls *don't* have dynamic locations.

Comment: There is no support for this built-in at all.  It just isn't anything anybody ever needs.  Users like finding things back in predictable locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing I came up with was using a `TabControl` and hiding the tabs as in [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2005/11/14/430591.aspx)